# Detect IE setting: check for newer versions of stored pages "never"

Tags: asp.net, javascript, security, internet-explorer, caching

I understand there isn't a way to interrogate a users IE settings directly due to security reasons, but is there a way to derive this answer with some other mechanism?  I would like to stop a user from using my site if the setting "Check for newer versions of stored pages" is set to "Never".  Any suggestions?

Is there a way I could test for this using javascript?  An example of what I am trying to accomplish is this:  *While it is not possible to check IE settings to see if you are running a popup blocker, that is a way to "test" for a popup blocker via javascript.  I am looking for something similiar but for the cache setting, not the popup blocker.*

Comment: The setting in question is completely ignored if your pages properly specify a freshness lifetime using either Cache-Control or Expires headers.

Answer (score 0):

Append something to the querystring that is unlikely to have been used before (a datestring, a random number).

That will make IE 6 request the page again, as far as IE is concerned, its another page.

So if you have `http://somepage.com/dontcachethis.html` you'd replace this with something like `http://somepage.com/dontcachethis.html?please=23143425` where you asign `please` a random number.

Comment: I understand that but someone could just bookmark the old URL.  I am looking for a way to test for this IE setting.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to your web pages:

```
meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache"
meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0"
```

This forces the user's browser to reload the pages every time, regardless of the browser's cache settings.

Answer (score 0):

I've not implemented this yet, but this is my plan:

- Write out a date onto the page that is on an attribute of some HTML element (this should be written server side...writing it with javascript will defeat the purpose)
- Using javascript, load in the date.  If it is over a certain amount of time, I can assume they have not loaded a fresh copy of the page.  If that is the case, continue on...

If I've detected that they have an old version of a page, I could do a couple things:

1. I could warn them of this problem.  I could show them the setting that they need to change.
2. I could redirect them to the same page but add something onto the querystring so it looks like a different page to the browser.  If I do this, I would add something in my javascript that knows about this potential redirect loop.